# CSS spacing issue - Not sure what is causing the space

Tags: css

I am working on this page http://www.inboundio.com/plans/, now there is additional white space in first tr below the text "Software + service" and "Software" is (see image http://i.imgur.com/DEb9ccp.png)

I thought the space is coming from here but even after editing/removing it, I am not seeing any change.

```
#table_head {
    height: 40px;
}
```

This seems to be some css overriding problem, can someone tell me the error.

Comment: link specific question not appreciated mate!!!

Comment: Use something like `Google Chrome`, right click and `Inspect Element` to view the styling properties of specific elements. Playing with the styling there makes these kinds of issues really easy to solve and prevents clutter on `SO`.

Comment: @NoobEditor - I understand the downvote and have no problem with it but posting the whole css + html is very difficult in this case which will cause more confusion, just posting the main link helps others to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem:

`.col2 > div` and `.col3 > div` has fixed `height: 105px` - that's one thing. The other things is that the whole div is positioned `top: -30px`. I assume it was your intention but you must be aware that even if the `<div>` is moved `30px` up, its parent (`<td>`) will still behave like the `<div>` is on its static place. It means, you'll have additional `30px` space at the bottom.

### Solution:

To fix the problem I'd suggest replacing the `top` property with `margin-top` and of course remove the fixed `height`. I also suggest keeping the `position: relative` to make sure that any *borders*, *background* etc. from `<td>` won't cover the overlaping `<h4>`.

```css
#table_head > td > div {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: What is the fix for it ?

Comment: actually I do want the overlapping, but just want to reduce the white space. Unfortunately the above code is not working.

Comment: Well, it worked when I used it in your website. You must have had some other issues.

Comment: Ok, I am still working on it, give me 5 mins, any chance you can post it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Thanks it worked, I had to remove " top:-30px;", accepting this as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

i inspected the elemt and it has bottom margin, it was causing the issue

```
<h4 style="margin-bottom:0px">Managed</h4>
```

give it style like this

or through css

```
.clo2 div h4
{
margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Alright, this is aligning the text to center but still not reducing the vertical space